# An inequality involving an exponential rate of sum

Tags: probability, inequality

I'm having trouble understanding the conclusion in the proof of Cramér's Theorem in $\mathbb{R}^d$ in the book by Dembo/Zeitouni:

We have the following: $\delta>0$ is fixed, $B_{y,\delta}$ is the ball of radius $\delta$ around some $y\in\mathbb{R}^d$ and

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\log \nu_n(B_{y,\delta}) \geq - \Lambda^*(y) > -\infty, \quad (1)$$
$$\mu_n(B_{y,2\delta}) \geq \nu_n(B_{y,\delta}) - \mathbb{P}(|V| \geq \sqrt{Mn}\delta), \; \forall M>0,  \quad (2)$$
and
$$\limsup_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \log \mathbb{P}(|V| \geq \sqrt{Mn}\delta) \leq - \frac{M\delta^2}{2}. \quad (3)$$
Here $\mu_n, \nu_n, \mathbb{P}$ are all probability measures. 
From these inequalities the authors conclude that
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \mu_n(B_{y,\delta}) \geq - \Lambda^*(y). \quad (4)$$

What I have tried:
From (2) follows
 $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \log \left(\mu_n(B_{y,2\delta}) + \mathbb{P}(|V| \geq \sqrt{Mn}\delta) \right) \geq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \log\nu_n(B_{y,\delta}) , \; \forall M>0, \quad $$
If the left hand side would equal
$$\max \{ \liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \log \mu_n(B_{y,2\delta}),  \liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \log \mathbb{P}(|V| \geq \sqrt{Mn}\delta)\} $$
the claim would follow, since because of (3) the maximum would be $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \log \mu_n(B_{y,2\delta})$ and then (1) implies (4).

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Because of (3) the claim would also follow if
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\log (\mu_n (B_{y,2\delta} +  \mathbb{P}(|V| \geq \sqrt{Mn}\delta) ) = \max \{ \liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \log \mu_n (B_{y,2\delta}), \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \log \mathbb{P}(|V| \geq \sqrt{Mn}\delta)).$$